# Resolve Assemblies in Design Automation for Revit

Tags: dll, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I'm using Design Automation to modify family parameter values based on data in a CSV file. The CSV library I am using depends on Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces v1.0.0.0+ and the JSON library I'm using depends on Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces v7.0.0.0. I can only include one or the other in my AppBundle (due to duplicate naming in the same directory), but either way I get an Exception from the DA4R runtime based on whichever is missing:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

My local version of this add-in uses an app.config file with a binding redirect to resolve this but my DA4R version isn't working because it doesn't include that file.

Based on [this example](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/05/rvtva3c-assembly-resolver.html) I think a custom assembly resolve function would work but I don't know how to access the location of the assembly files.

The local runtime directory only includes my working files and not my AppBundle files. I can see those files are located at `T:\Aces\Applications\ffc6436bec04d21d55ea37de192e1fe6.<APPNAME>.<ACTIVITYNAME>[##].package` but for obvious reasons do not want to hard-code my current version number into my source code.

Am I on the right track or is there an easier way?

Comment: It must be a .exe.config file to be effective, which does mean that you have to copy acad.exe.config (or whatever the .exe name) into the CAD install directory.  Not that this helps, a bindingRedirect doesn't solve a file-not-found problem.  Real problem is that the CLR just doesn't look in the add-in directory for any dependencies.  It looks in the GAC first, the CAD install directory next.  You could use the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event to help.

Comment: @blake You are on the right track. Assembly resolver is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access AppBundle files during the running of WorkItem. Please refer to: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/handle-command-line-arguments and https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/store-template-documents-appbundle

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the following lines to access my "duplicate" .dll and load it correctly:

```
string assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

string fullPath = assemblyPath + @"\lib\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll";

Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullPath);
```

Comment: When and where are you calling this? Are you calling it from `OnStartup()`?

Comment: I am calling it within my HandleDesignAutomationReadyEvent()

Comment: I'd recommend using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` so it gets triggered when it is needed. Similar to Jeremey's [blog](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/05/rvtva3c-assembly-resolver.html) you shared in your description.

Answer (score 0):

The assembly resolver method you use for your desktop addin, should work in DA app bundle as well.

```cs
public ExternalDBApplicationResult OnStartup(Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.ControlledApplication app)
{
    DesignAutomationBridge.DesignAutomationReadyEvent += HandleDesignAutomationReadyEvent;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolve;
    return ExternalDBApplicationResult.Succeeded;
}

private static readonly string AssemblyLocation  = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
private static readonly string AssemblyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(AssemblyLocation);
private static string GetPathInAssemblyDirectory(string filename) => Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, filename);

private static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
   // You could either check for input argument against a hardcoded
   // list of dlls (in your case Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll)
   // or like below, check if the dll attempted to be loaded (as
   // per to the input argument is something you bundled.
   string filename = args.Name.Split(',')[0] + ".dll".ToLower();
   string assemblyFilename = GetPathInAssemblyDirectory(filename);
   if (!File.Exists(assemblyFilename))
      return null;

   return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFilename);
}

public void HandleDesignAutomationReadyEvent(object sender, DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs e)
{
   // Your code here...
   // Your code here...
   // Your code here...
   e.Succeeded = true;
}
```

Note: I am leaving a generic answer above. But looking at your other answer, in your case, the input dll is in `lib` sub folder, so you will have to account for that.